# Ember CLI + Ember Data + Simple Auth: authorize gets not called

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

i am using Ember CLI + Ember Data + Simple Auth. The authenticator is working fine. But when im am doing a Rest Call with Ember Data Rest Adapter `this.store.findAll("user");` the authorize function in my custom authorizer don't gets called.

The Rest API Endpoint is on an other domain, so i added the url to the `crossOriginWhitelist` in my environment.js.

**environment.js:**

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        // some configuration
    };

    ENV['simple-auth'] = {
        crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://api.xxxx.com'],
        authorizer: 'authorizer:xxxx',
        routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',
    };

    return ENV;
};
```

**authorizer**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';

var XXXXAuthorizer = Base.extend({
    authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
        // Some Code, gets not called, damn it :(
    }
});



export default {
    name: 'authorization',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container) {
        container.register('authorizer:xxxx', XXXXAuthorizer);
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
....
        <script>
            window.XXXXWebclientENV = {{ENV}};
            window.ENV = window.MyAppENV;
            window.EmberENV = window.XXXXWebclientENV.EmberENV;
        </script>
        <script>
            window.XXXXWebclient = require('xxxx-webclient/app')['default'].create(XXXXWebclientENV.APP);
        </script>
....
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  For me it was the `crossOriginWhitelist` config.

I set it like this:

```js
// config/environment.js

ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  crossOriginWhitelist: ['*']   // <-- Make sure it's an array, not a string
};
```

to see if I could get it working (I could), then I could narrow it down to figure out exactly what URL I should use to enforce the restriction (port number and hostname etc).

**Don't leave it like that though!**

You should actually figure out what URL works for the whitelist, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I have same setup but the authorize function is not being called. May be you can try by adding the port number in your `crossOriginWhiteList url`.

I am adding `window.ENV = window.MyAppENV` line in new initializer which runs before simple-auth. You have added that in index file and may be that is the reason why simple-auth is not able to read your configuration.

Does the other configuration `routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',` works properly? If not then this might be the reason. Try adding new initializer like

```
  export default {
  name: 'simple-auth-config',
  before: 'simple-auth',

    initialize: function() {
        window.ENV = window.MyAppNameENV;
    }    
 };
```

Comment: I just checked for same domain and it works fine. So it is definitely a cross origin domain issue. I think the simple-auth is not able to read the `crossOriginWhiteList` configuration.

Comment: It started working for me. I previously defined port number also which was wrong. So after I removed that port number it is working fine for me.